# Regex validator does not work with Django admin forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I try to use a RegexValidator with a CharField, but I can't make it work...

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'Name', validators =
           [RegexValidator(regex="[a-z]", message="Not cool", code="nomatch")])
```

I then just register it with

```
admin.site.register(Configuration)
```

But then in the admin forms, it accepts any possible name... Is the validation system suppose to work like that, or am I missing something ?

Comment: I have a similar problem, I added two `RexexValidator`s to one of my fields but when from a shell I mess with this field and save the object it doesn't raise any `ValidationError` exception. I'm a bit confused, I thought this was in a model to prevent any dodgy data to get to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex checks that your value contains a single character from a-z. So it allows `a`, but it also allows `a1`.

Try changing the regex to:

```
regex=r"^[a-z]+$"
```

By including `^` and `$` to mark the beginning and end of string, you make sure that your string contains only characters from a-z. The `+` allows multiple characters.

Comment: Thanks, I thought ^ and $ where somehow automatic.